# Does UI5 support current ecmascript out of its library?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, sapui5

Does sapui5 support ecmascript6 (or 5) directly from its library? In other words: when I use the sapui5 library am I then independent of browsers that do not yet support ecmascript6 (or 5)?
And if sapui5 *does* support ecmascript out of its lib, which sapui5 version supports which ecmascript version?
If there are only some polyfills like for example the ES6 promise, what are they? Are they specified somewhere in the API so I can safely use and rely on them?

I have searched for "sapui5 ecmascript" here on browserstack but did not find any answer. I searched the [Openui5 Toolkit](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html) but also did not find this desired info there. The only [suitable info](https://scn.sap.com/thread/3759013) I've found did not give me the answer to my question.

Comment: SAPUI5 obviously does not contain a Javascript runtime -- it is just a framework / set of libraries -- and as such does not 'include' ECMAScript 5 or 6; it merely runs on top of it. As a result, if your browser / compiler / runtime / nodejs / whatever supports ECMAScript 6, you can perfectly use it with SAPUI5

Comment: According to [this][1] blog "UI5 has an ECMA Script 6 Polyfill jQuery.sap.promise". That's what I mean.[1]: http://jasper07.secondphase.com.au/

Comment: I see. But that is just the ES6 Promise, because the jQuery promise (which is the default in SAPUI5) behaves a bit flakey, to say the least ;) There may be more ES6 polyfills in UI5 (I would not know them, I'm only aware of the Promise polyfill) so it's not that the complete ES6 specification is capsulated in polyfills in UI5

Comment: SAPUI5 does only have a few polyfills that it needs internally. It does not have a complete ES6 polyfill (which is not possible because ES6 introduces new keywords).

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some polyfills in SAPUI5. A search in the [OpenUI5 Github](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=polyfill) lists `Promise`, `string.prototype.normalize()`, `Array.prototype.every()` and `Array.prototype.indexOf()`. But i guess this list is not complete.

I think you *cannot* rely on them. They are not officially documented. Most of them are only loaded and applied when needed by some controls or classes. Also beware that SAP can change the implementation of the polyfills at any time and change the conditions when the polyfills are applied and when not.

As an example the Promise polyfill has not been applied to Safari (which has a native Promise) until SAPUI5 v1.34.0, and MS Edge (which also has a native Promise) until SAPUI5 version 1.34.4 ([changelog](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#releasenotes.html)).

Comment: It is incomplete. For example `Array.prototype.find()` is missing